# Is there a way run a python script on another server?

Tags: python, django, iis, iis-6

I have a **Djnago** web application on **IIS** **6** on one server. Is there a way that from this website I call another **python** **script** that is on another server in such a way that that script just run itself there?

Calling or Runnig that script in the usual way as internet says, is not working.

I always get the error of `os.getcwd()` and it also doesn't allow to change that directory.

I just want to run that **python script** there on that server from this server.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would recommend using a framework like `fabric` or `winrm` if you want to run a python script on another server.  Those frameworks use ssh or windows remoting functionality, respectively, to allow a python program to execute other commands (including python scripts) on other systems.  If the target machine is a windows machine, be forewarned that you can run into all sorts of UAC issues doing normal operations.